# Xamarin Forms error while writing anim R$anim.class

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Hello i am update to visual studio community 2017 15.5 on debug i have this error

```
obj\Debug\android\src\android\support\compat\R.java:11: error: error while writing anim: obj\Debug\android\bin\classes\android\support\compat\R$anim.class (El proceso no tiene acceso al archivo porque est├í siendo utilizado por otro proceso)
3>      public static final class anim {
3>                          ^
3>  Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
3>  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3>  Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
3>  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3>  1 error
```

Comment: It says that a file is being used and cannot be written to. Check what thing is keeping it open and close it.

Comment: We are looking into this issue currently. See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/155693/xamarin-android-project-cannot-build-because-ranim.html

Answer (score 12):

**EDIT: This bug should be fixed now if you update to Visual Studio version 15.5.2**
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#15.5.2
"Release Date: December 14, 2017 - Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5.2
Top Issues Fixed in this Release
These are the customer-reported issues addressed in this release:

Xamarin Android project cannot build because R$anim.class is in use."

Short Answer

1- Open the task manager, and kill the MSBuild.exe operation.

2- If 1 didnt work, close and re-open Visual Studio
2a. Also make sure you close the emulator. (edit)

Longer Answer-

I’ve started to occasionally get the same build errors which is some variation of 
“Xamarin Android project cannot build because R$anim.class is in use”

I’m looking into it and it looks like this is a pretty recent issue they are having since the Xamarin Android 15.5 release. 
Here’s a link to a thread where the bug is being reported and actively getting worked on. As of the time of this email a fix hasn’t has been pushed yet, but there is a quick fix that worked for me. 
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/155693/xamarin-android-project-cannot-build-because-ranim.html

It appears the issue is in some way tied to the MSBuild processes. 
Open the task manager, and kill the MSBuild.exe operation.

After that, maybe a clean and rebuild, the android emulator seems to work. 
If that doesn’t work, closing and re-opening VS seems to do the trick. But I would try the task manager first, it might be a faster way to clear the error.

Edit - 
I also close the emulator while I'm restarting my visual studio. I could be wrong on this, but it looks like it keeps making extra instances of MSbuild.exe and needs a good close and re-launch.

Comment: VS thread: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/155693/xamarin-android-project-cannot-build-because-ranim.html

Comment: Sorry @AlexeiSarmiento thats all the troubleshooting I have on an error like this. I know the 15.5.1 version of visual studio just got released with some bug fixes to xamarin. If you update maybe that will help?

Comment: But there can be more than one instance of MSBuild.exe, I end all of them. I would also try closing the emulator.

Comment: Thanks Tim, the problem persist,

Comment: Thanks Tim, the problem persist. I made a new solution with the same structure and I import all files, after this, there are no more errors

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that I am seeing the same error after the VS2017 15.5 upgrade. It appears that this issue has been filed with Xamarin support [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=60992).

I am running a Xamarin Forms app. While restarting VS does appear to resolve the issue, I am unable to deploy in debug mode. Even after a restart, when the app is deployed/launched into a device or emulator, it crashes immediately. However, the application can be launched in Release mode successfully.

Still searching for a fix. In the meantime, building a new dev VM with the 15.4 version of VS (available for download [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017)).

Comment: Continuing to search for a fix, I ran across someone having the same issue with the 15.5 Preview, [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/155693/xamarin-android-project-cannot-build-because-ranim.html). Unfortunately, no solution was ever provided.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the obj folder inside project and restarting fix the issue. But it keeps on coming every time i add a folder on Resources or something

Answer (score 1):

Use taskill command to kill your various msbuild executable process. Note you may need to be admin to do this.

```
taskkill /im msbuild.exe /f /t
```

Answer (score 0):

Same here, always problems when xamarin/ms releases new ver :-(
Restart VS helps for a while...

Answer (score 0):

Did you solved your problem? Restarting VS help though.. weird error

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Please write a comment instead.